# how to know if a file was ever modified in the git repo after adding it

Tags: git

I am using a third party library js file.

How can I check if I have ever modified it after adding it (after downloading the copy from the library's website) using GIT?

Also how do I know when I added  a specific file to git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the log for that file alone:

```
 git log -- /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the difference/modifications on the file using the following command

```
  git diff ../path to file
```